# Including simplemde in Laravel Uncaught TypeError: simplemde is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to use simplemde in a default Laravel project like so
app.js:

```
window.simplemd = require('simplemde');
```

Then as per the simplemd documentation I also added this to app.js:

```
var simplemde = new simplemde({ element: document.getElementById("md") });
```

This gives me an error of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: simplemde is not a constructor
```

I'm unsure what it means that simplemde is not a constructor when the documentation says it is. Can anyone see whats happening here?

Comment: is this `md` a textarea?

Comment: yes with an ID of md <textarea id="md"></textarea> I don't think that is the issue, the problem is it can't construct an instance of simplemde

Comment: can you try capitalizing the class name like `new SimpleMDE` from the docs it's capital.

Comment: that results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: SimpleMDE is not defined`

Comment: Try changing `require('simplemde')` to `require('simplemde').default;`

Comment: Also check this @ https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor/issues/355

Answer (score 1):

You should import the library as following

```
var SimpleMDE = require('simplemde')
```

and then call it as:

```
let simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ element: document.getElementById("text") });
```